# Как получить доступ к открытым вкладкам браузера.

Tags: tcp-ip, webbrowser, c++

Идея такова: <br>
Аудио-плеер , при просмотре видео на YouTUBE или иных сервисах , автоматически ставится на паузу. Идея отличная , нужная , аудио-плеер написан. А о главном не подумал. 
Написано все на с++ , что посоветуете?

Comment: Какой отношение С++ имеет к браузерному приложению?

    Создал отличную машину, всё продумал, хорошо ездит. А о главном не подумал. Не самолёт.

Comment: Если ёж живет в лесу а лиса оранжевая на каком этаже живёт Петя? :)

Comment: Там василий , тут ахмед , иди лесом если не можешь нормально ответить :-)

Answer (score 1):

Так а причем тут открытые вкладки браузера и видео на YouTUBE, у браузера вообще может не быть вкладок, вдобавок браузеры разные, ну и в третьих видео не во вкладке браузера воспроизводится, а в окошке Adobe Flash Player'а.

***Наверное***, можно поставить глобальный хук и следить за открытием окон Adobe Flash Player, и тормозить свой плеер когда такое окно открывается и восстанавливаться когда оно закрывается, или заморочиться еще чуть чуть, перехватывать сообщения уже открытых окон и при "play" останавливаться, при "pause\stop" возобновляться.

Comment: сейчас перебираются на html5 , где флеш не используется , а используются внутренние кодеки. В этом и проблема

Comment: Ну тогда перехватывать сообщения еще и браузера, если это конкретно браузер воспроизводит что либо, то какое то сообщение на play\stop в виндах то у него наверняка есть!!!